# Why is my Z-Index Not Working? Perplexing

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

HERE IS THE CODEPEN:[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Austin-Pacholek/pen/poqaxGM)

```
  `
```

```
  <div id="links">
            <div id="fancy"></div>  (the top div is closed later on)`
```

here is the css:

```
     #links {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 60px;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #50602a 50%, #799934 90%);
    position: relative;
    **z-index: 822;**
    }
    #fancy {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto -10px auto;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    **z-index: -10001;**
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

Here is the picture:

[White div should stack LOWER than Green div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9NzA.png)

I've tried restacking the HTML code. The google computed z-index is correct. The top div is set to relative, the lower div is absolute. I'm officially perplexed and bamboozled.

Here is the website url:

totalcurbappeal.com/reviews

Comment: It doesn't work because your `<div id="fancy"></div>` is nested within `<div id="links"></div>`. A child's `z-index` is set to the same stacking index as its parent. If I understood correctly what you want to achieve there's no need to use `z-index`, just use `border`. Change the CSS of `#fancy` like i did in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2vqtp63h/